# How to build an array comprised of two others using only particular elements of each?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I writing a little program to generate some bogus top-ten sales numbers for book sales.  I'm trying to do this in as compact a fashion as possible and do it without using MySQL or another DB.

I have written out what I want to happen.  I've created a bogus catalog array and a bogus sales array corresponding sales to the index of the catalog entries. That part all works great.

I want to create a third array that includes all the titles from the catalog array with the sales numbers from the sales array, like a join in a DB, but without any DB.  I can't figure out how to do that part of it though.  I think once I have it in there I can sort it the way I want it, but making that third array is killing.  I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong or how to do it right.

So given the following code:

```
require 'random_word'

class BestOnline

  def initialize

    @catalog = Array.new
    @sales = Array.new
    @topten = Array.new

    inventory = rand(50) + 10
    days = rand(1..50)
    now = Time.now
    yesterday = now - 86400
    saleshistory = now - (days * 86400)


    (1..inventory).each do
      @catalog << {
        :title => "#{RandomWord.adjs.next.capitalize} #{RandomWord.nouns.next.capitalize}",
        :price => rand(5.99..29.99).round(2)}
    end

    (0..days).each do
      @sales << {
        :id => rand(0..@catalog.count),
        :salescount => rand(0..24),
        :date => rand(saleshistory..now) }
    end

  end


  def bestsellers

    @sales.each do
        # THIS DOESNT WORK AND I'M STUCK AS HOW TO FIX IT. 
        # @topten << {
        #     :title => @catalog[:id],
        #     :salescount => @sales[:salescount]
        # }
    end

    puts @topten.group_by{ |tt| tt[:salescount]}.sort_by{ |k,v| -k}.first(10)

  end

end

BestOnline.new.bestsellers
```

How can I create a third array that contains the titles and number of sales and output the result of the top-ten books sold?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need input data, expected output, and the *minimal* code necessary to demonstrate the problem you're having. Asking us to create data wastes our time, and slows you getting an answer. No expected output makes it difficult for us to tell if we've supplied a correct answer because we have to get into a "is this right" loop with you. And making us wade through lots of code to figure out the affected part slows us again. So, help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
def bestsellers

    @sales.each do |sale|
        @topten << { 
            title: @catalog[sale[:id]][:title],
            salescount: sale[:salescount] }
    end

    @topten.sort! { |x, y| y[:salescount] <=> x[:salescount] }

    puts @topten.first(10)

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write:

```
def bestsellers(sales)
  sales.max_by(10) { |h| h[:salescount][:salescount]] }
end

puts bestsellers(sales)
```

[Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) was permitted to have an argument in Ruby v2.2.

There are several problems with the way you've structured your code. Now that you have running code (by incorporating @fbonds66's answer), I suggest you post it at SO's sister-site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby). The purpose of CR is to suggest improvements to working code. If you read through some of the questions and answers there I think you will be impressed.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the dereferencing wrong trying to build the 3rd array of the 1st two:

```
@sales.each do |sale|
    @topten << {
        :title => @catalog[sale[:id]][:title],
        :salescount => sale[:salescount]
    }
end
```

I needed to work on the hash returned from .each as |sale| and use correct syntax to get what I was after from the other arrays.